# lastcol =Range("a7").End(xlRight).Column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to find the last column in a range with data in it (the width of the range is variable month on month). The formula I am using throws an *Application defined or Object defined error*. This is the code:

```
lastcol = Worksheets("Current Month").Range("H7").End(xlRight).Column
```

I'm puzzled as the code below works:

```
lastrow = Worksheets("Current Month").Range("B7").End(xlDown).Row
```

Comment: Range is wrong, you have selected a cell ie H7,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `xlToRight` instead of `xlRight`. These are not the same constant. The `End` function does not understand the xlRight constant.

Comment: Cheers for this, I was blind to that!

Comment: @RosscoPicotrain These constants' names are pretty much confusing... Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

To find the last column in the first row use the below code

```
dim lastcolumn as long 

lastcolumn = Worksheets("Current Month").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Comment: Newjenn's answer is correct, because xlToRight finds the next non-empty cell from your cell towards right. You must start from the extreme right of the row, and serch the leftmost non-empty column, in order to find the very last non-empty column.

Comment: There are further columns containing data further right so I'm not looking to find the last column in the enitre sheet. A.S.H has found the issue , i was being a dumbass and using xlRight and not xltoRight